# Tranform xml to xml dynamically by Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

Here, I added my xml code. I need to transform the xml to dynamically. if I have number of employees, I have wanted to arrange the employee in department wise.

this is my input file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmployeeList>
<employee>
<eid>r-001</eid>
<ename>Dinesh R</ename>
<age>35</age>
<deptcode>d1</deptcode>
<deptname>Research</deptname>
<salary>20000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<eid>r-002</eid>
<ename>Madhu V</ename>
<age>40</age>
<deptcode>d1</deptcode>
<deptname>Research</deptname>
<salary>12000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<eid>s-001</eid>
<ename>Kanmani S</ename>
<age>35</age>
<deptcode>d2</deptcode>
<deptname>Sales</deptname>
<salary>30000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<eid>s-002</eid>
<ename>Sujitha R</ename>
<age>40</age>
<deptcode>d2</deptcode>
<deptname>Sales</deptname>
<salary>12000</salary>
</employee>
```

I need the output to be grouping employing in the same department. My excepted output is,

```
<deptname name="Research">
<employee>
    <eid>r-001</eid>
    <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
    <age>35</age>
    <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
    <deptname>Research</deptname>
    <salary>20000</salary>
 </employee>
 <employee>
    <eid>r-002</eid>
    <ename>Madhu V</ename>
    <age>40</age>
    <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
    <deptname>Research</deptname>
    <salary>12000</salary>
 </employee>
 </deptname>
 <deptname name="Sales">
<employee>
    <eid>s-001</eid>
    <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
    <age>35</age>
    <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
    <deptname>Sales</deptname>
    <salary>30000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
    <eid>s-002</eid>
    <ename>Sujitha R</ename>
    <age>40</age>
    <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
    <deptname>Sales</deptname>
    <salary>12000</salary>
 </employee>
 </deptname>
```

I have tried this, but I couldn't get my expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We help you, but we don't do the work for you. Please show your attempt.

Comment: yeah @Utkanos. I didn't put post without trying. I am a fresher and also I am learning too. I have tried more times, but i couldn't get so I need to know the result. so y i posted here.

Comment: Can you say if you can use XSLT 2.0 or above? Thank you!

Comment: I used XSLT 1.0 only. I dont have aware more on XSLT 2.0. Now only I am learning. I tried the below code but its shows Xpath error.

Comment: You should read up on a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" for XSLT 1.0. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeList">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="child::deptname">
        <xsl:element name="deptname">
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it show error.. 

ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group''

Comment: @NagabalajiVijayakumar which version use

Comment: @NagabalajiVijayakumar use version 2.0

Comment: I changed version 2.0. Eventhough it throws the same error.. Actually I am working in eclipse and I am using tranformer.java for that to transform the file xml and xsl. In xsl file, I have written the code and i changed the version 2.0 in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeeList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="employee" group-by="deptname">
                <deptname name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </deptname>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
You may try this...
```

Comment: I tried your code but it shows error.. ERROR: 'Unsupported XSL element 'w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group''

Comment: Are you using xslt 1.0

Comment: Now I changed 2.0 but still i didn't get the o/p.